# Can I use the array of records after batch insert in Activerecord-import gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bulkinsert, activerecord-import

So in the readme, it does this

```
books = []
10.times do |i|
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}") 
end 
Book.import books
```

but can we also use the books array to do a loop to further modify each records in the array or is that not possible? Such instance was not stated in readme

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that very easily, nothing happens with the objects until the import, Book.new just creates a new instance in memory - it does not touch the database.  E.g.

```
books = []
10.times do |i|
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}") 
end 
books.each_with_index do |book,i|
  book.name = "new book name #{i}"
end
Book.import books
```

see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html

Comment: Yes, I have considered that case but I need to use ids created from first import onto a second mass import. I was wondering if it behaves like a single activerecord insert where I can continue to use the variable after insertion.

Comment: ah yes - I didn't read your question correctly.   You can synchronize the objects with the database - Book.import books, , :synchronize => books, :synchronize_keys => [:name] - then each element of books will have an id value